# How can I prevent System.StackOverflowException in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting the error as given below. Please help me.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EbixExchange.NamedItems.Resolvers.dll.`

What is the reason of occurring this error and how can I handle  this error in C#?

there is a function which is returning objects.

```
public object GetObject(NamedItem namedItem)          
 {

    return someObject;

 }
```

this function is calling again and again.

Comment: Maybe showing the part of your code where it happen will help?

Comment: Examine the stack trace. It should show you the method(s) that are calling themselves recursively (which is almost always the cause of SOs)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever When `StackOverflowException` occurs you'll not be able to see the stacktrace

Comment: Go through this - http://www.dotnetperls.com/stackoverflowexception

Comment: May be Infinite Looop .. i think you performing some recurcive operation and your operation is noy terminating  thus after a period of time you got a popup of this exception

Comment: Is `someObject` a property or a field? If it's a property, does that property call `GetObject`?

Answer (score 9):

> What is the reason of occurring this error and how can I handle this error in C#?

The reason for the error is an unbounded recursion. The way you handle it is: you don't. You **eliminate the unbounded recursion**.

Comment: Added some code please look in to the code